# How to write a python test for environment variable that is loaded on import

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I want to test how system behaves while changing initial environmenet variable.

the_file.py:

```py
import os

from fastapi import APIRouter

PREFIX = os.getenv("SERVICE_PREFIX") or "/default"

router = APIRouter(prefix=PREFIX)
```

test.py:

```py
# Following test is using pytest-mock library for mocker fixture
import os

def test_prefix_value_digested_correctly(mocker):
    mocker.patch.dict(
        os.environ,
        {
            "SERVICE_PREFIX": "/services",
        },
        clear=True,
    )
    from the_file import router
    assert router.prefix == "/services"
```

The above test fails because environment variable is read on the initial import:

```
assert router.prefix == "/services"
E       AssertionError: assert '/default' == '/services'
E         - /services
E         + /default
```

I could solve this by creating a function `get_prefix` which reads the environment on the go, but that is not the goal here. Goal is a sanity check - "If I set SERVICE_PREFIX env variable, router.prefix should be changed".

Is there a way to dynamically send such environment variable to python unittests/pytest?

Comment: Use a function to determine `PREFIX` so you are able to mock the value.

Comment: I want to avoid that here to avoid errors on setup. Function can be working fine, but still - I can make an error on setting up for router prefix value.

Answer (score 2):

Use a function to determine `PREFIX`, try not to test 'global state':

```
import unittest
import os
from unittest import mock


def get_prefix():
    return os.getenv("SERVICE_PREFIX") or "/default"


class TestMyApi(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'SERVICE_PREFIX': '/FOO'})
    def test_get_prefix_from_os(self):
        self.assertEqual(get_prefix(), "/FOO")

    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {})
    def test_get_prefix_default(self):
        self.assertEqual(get_prefix(), "/default")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Out:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: I'm aware of this option, however, here I do not want to use it(do not want to change code to comply with tests).

If I do, I can still make mistakes on setting the value like:
```
prefix = get_prefix();
router = APIRouter(prefix="");
```
The "" works on develop, but not on production environment and bug is passed through.